# How to check if an entry is created with one object in another model in entire django project?

Tags: django

Suppose I have a warehouse model.
Now before deleting this warehouse object i wanna check that if this particular object is used in some other model or not?

```
class Warehouse(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, default=0)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, default=0)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=0)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)
```

now I have 1500 different models in my project so i cannot write a query to check whether it's pk exists in them or not so what's the fastest way to do this ?

Comment: Usually you would have used `on_delete=models.PROTECT` for everything that *refers* to the `Warehouse` and thus should protect `Warehouse`s from being deleted.

Comment: Yes I did that but for some certain reasons I wanna check the same before editing, so how do I manage that?

Comment: Especially if there are models with `related_name='...+'`, this will be quite painful...

Comment: Can you explain a bit please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can introspect your model and then query the relations in reverse, for example:

```
from django.db.models.fields.reverse_related import ForeignObjectRel


def is_referenced(model_obj):
    for rel in type(model_obj)._meta.get_fields():
        if isinstance(rel, ForeignObjectRel):
            accessor_name = rel.get_accessor_name()
            if accessor_name.endswith('+'):
                raise ValueError('can not access certain relations in reverse')
            if getattr(model_obj, accessor_name).exists():
                return True
    return False
```

here we thus enumerate over the relations and check for relations in reverse, so models that have a `ForeignKey`, `OneToOneField` and `ManyToManyField` that *target* the `Warehouse` model in this case. In that case we will use the reverse relation to check if such objects exist.

You can thus use the function `is_referenced(some_warehouse)`, to check if `some_warehouse` is referenced *directly* by some other model.

It will however *not* work if there are relations with a [**`related_name=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) that end with `+`, since that means there is no reverse accessor.